# local docker - nginx is online on https unsecure

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, ssl, https

I'm trying to run react application iwthin Nginx on docker app is running and online
but its not scured, its working on https - Vite react if it matter

Common Name (CN)    localhost
Organizational Unit (OU)    Eng
Issued On   Sunday, January 7, 2024 at 10:00:13 AM
Expires On  Monday, January 6, 2025 at 10:00:13 AM

package json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
```

nginx conf

```
events {
    # Event-driven configuration
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Global SSL settings (optional, can be overridden in server blocks)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    # Include server configurations
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # Further http configurations

    # Server block example
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name your_domain.com; # Replace with your domain name

        # SSL settings for this server
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;

        # Other server-specific configurations
    }
}
```

default.conf

```
server {
    # Listen on port 80 for incoming connections
    listen 80;

    # Define the root directory where your files are located
    # This should be the path to your built React application
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Specify the file to serve as index
    index index.html;

    # Handle Single Page Application (SPA) routing:
    # Attempt to serve any requested file or route, fall back to index.html if not found
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Custom error pages (optional)
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        internal;
    }

    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server {
    # Listen on port 80 for incoming connections
    listen 443;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;

    # Recommended SSL settings
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    # Define the root directory where your files are located
    # This should be the path to your built React application
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Specify the file to serve as index
    index index.html;

    # Handle Single Page Application (SPA) routing:
    # Attempt to serve any requested file or route, fall back to index.html if not found
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Custom error pages (optional)
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        internal;
    }
}
```

Docker image

```
# Step 1: Use an official Node runtime as a parent image
FROM node:20.10.0 as build

# Step 2: Set the working directory in the container
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Step 3: Copy the package.json files and install dependencies
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install --verbose
RUN npm set audit false


# Step 4: Copy the rest of your app's source code
COPY . /app

# Step 5: Build your app
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Serve the application with Nginx
FROM nginx:alpine

# Step 6: Copy build artifacts from the 'build' stage to the Nginx directory

COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy SSL certificates
# Assume you have cert.pem and privkey.pem in your project directory
COPY cert.pem /etc/nginx/cert.pem
COPY privkey.pem /etc/nginx/privkey.pem

# Step 7: Expose both port 80 and 443 for Nginx
EXPOSE 80 443
```

How can I make it secure connection over https docker

```
docker run -p 443:443 some-name
```

[image]

Comment: In short: you have to have a properly created certificate for localhost (which is unknown here, no certificate details are known) and you need to make it explicitly trusted in the browser since no publicly trusted CA will issue a certificate for localhost (since localhost is not owned by a specific party).